# Разный учет количества элементов в выборке в IE

Tags: javascript

Вот допустим такой код: http://jsfiddle.net/TryrR/

В нормальных браузерах - ок, пишет 1, в IE - пишет 0.

Как решить эту проблему на чистом JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот такой фикс:

http://jsfiddle.net/TryrR/3/

> До появления стандарта HTML5 этот
> метод возвращал только те элементы, в
> которых предусмотрена поддержка
> атрибута name, в частности: iframe, a,
> input и другими.
>
> В современных браузерах тег не имеет
> значения, но старое поведение можно
> увидеть, попробовав пример ниже в IE10
> и до версии 10.
>
> В IE9- метод не найдёт элементы, для
> которых в стандарте нет атрибута name.

Отсюда: http://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom#getelementsbyname

Comment: Спасибище, работает.